# Semantic-ui-react: How do I trigger a Popup without it being click/hover?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

When submitting a form, I wish to show a small popup for 2.5 seconds if the server sends back a bad response.

The logic is fairly simple, however, I cannot figure out how to make this popup listen to a boolean somewhere in the state management(MobX in my case). I can get the content into the Popup just fine, however, the trigger is a button(and the content will show, if you click it) - But how do I make it listen to a boolean value somewhere?

Fairly simple class here:

```
import React from "react";
import { Popup, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { inject } from "mobx-react";
const timeoutLength = 2500;

@inject("store")
export default class ErrorPopup extends React.Component {

    state = {
        isOpen: false
    };

    handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: true
        });

        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                isOpen: false
            })
        }, timeoutLength)
    };

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        });
        clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    };

    render () {

        const errorContent = this.props.data;


        if(errorContent){
            return(
                <Popup
                    trigger={<Button content='Open controlled popup' />}
                    content={errorContent}
                    on='click'
                    open={this.state.isOpen}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    onOpen={this.handleOpen}
                    position='top center'
                />
            )
        }
    }
}
```

However, the trigger value is a button which is rendered if `this.props.data` is present. But that's not the behavior I wish; I simply want the popup to render(and thus trigger) if `this.props.data` is there; alternatively, I can provide a `true` value with props if need be.

But how do I make this component trigger without it being a hover/button?

Comment: It seems that the `open` prop is actually a pass-through to the `Portal` component (it is being used by `Popup`). That also makes sense why it is only possible to close it that way. When you pass `open=true` you actually pass that to `Portal`, however the `Popup` component is statically positioned and therefore *does not know the coordinates it needs to be in*. That is why it can only be opened through an event -- they use the `Event` object to get the cursor's position. See https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about passing in the isOpen prop? Then you could add some logic onto the componentWillReceiveProps hook:

```
import React from "react";
import { Popup, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { inject } from "mobx-react";
const timeoutLength = 2500;

@inject("store")
export default class ErrorPopup extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     isOpen: false,
   }
 };

  //This is where you trigger your methods
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(true === nextProps.isOpen){
      this.handleOpen();
    } else {
      this.handleClose();
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {

    this.setState({
      isOpen: true
    });

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      //No need to repeat yourself - use the existing method here
      this.handleClose();
    }, timeoutLength)
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false
    });
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  };

  render () {

    const errorContent = this.props.data;

    if(errorContent){
      return(
        <Popup
          trigger={<Button content='Open controlled popup' />}
          content={errorContent}
          on='click'
          open={this.state.isOpen}
          position='top center'
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Without a need of handling delay - you could simply pass in the isOpen prop and that would do the trick.

And here what it could look like in your parent component's render:

```
let isOpen = this.state.isOpen; 
<ErrorPopup isOpen={isOpen}/>
```

Set this value to control the popup, ideally, this should be a part of your parent component's state. Having a stateful component as a parent is important to make the popup re-rendered

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're solving here? The main problem still exists with the triggering being a click event on a button

Comment: No it doesn't. You just pass in the isOpen prop - and your popup state is getting updated accordingly. I'll take out the onClose / onOpen props from the Popup component if that confuses you.

Comment: The component you showed here would as far as I know not even render. And if `on` plus `trigger` are not there, nothing will be rendered at all, even if the errorContent is there?

Comment: You said "alternatively, I can provide a true value with props if need be." - of you provide that as a props.isOpen value - it will work just fine. That's how you " listen to a boolean somewhere in the state management"

Comment: Well, yeah, but it still won't solve the core issue: That triggering the popup is fully dependent on a button being clicked, which is still the case? Also, you're calling setState on a prop it seems? Sorry if my question was phrased poorly but I have absolutely no clue where you're going with this.

Comment: I'm not sure how that specific popup implementation works, but for most of them setting something like  open={this.state.isOpen} is enough to not use any event driven callbacks (like button clicks etc). So your only concern should be passing in the correct isOpen value from the parent component. And yes, we are triggering a state change from the prop change hook. To make that totally valid - you'll probably want to run some additional checks there (if the timeout is running at the moment etc.) - but I'll better leave it up to you to figure out

Comment: See the updated answer, maybe it makes things more clear

Comment: I suppose I get the gist of it and I'll try it out, but you're calling setState in a child component on what should essentially be props? The logic doesn't really hold in your example, which confuses me a tad? The component you wrote out obviously won't render, you're setting isOpen to a state that is never initialized(and thus it will throw an error). Also, it's still being triggered by a button(that's what you render in place of the component), so the core issue is still very much the same.

Comment: The "unintialized state" point is totally valid - I'll update my answer with a fixed code, thanks for pointing that out. The second one is cryptic. Are you telling that setting the "open" prop from true to false would hide the popup but setting from false to true wouldn't show it? I hope not because that's not the case. Check out this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mbxmyj

Answer (score 0):

Just use the property `open` as in the [documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/#usage-default-open). There is a separate example when popup is opened by default.